# Spotify PHP Api - {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}. Tried everything

Tags: php, api, sdk, spotify

EDIT
I found that if I edit the code to not use `http_build_query($parameters);`

to convert array of parameters into the url-string, but pass the strings directly to the url it works. So how is **http_build_query** destroying the **grant_type= authorization_code**?

ORIGINAL:

I'm using the php sdk api https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php

and trying to connect the user. I log in using the link

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?
          client_id=--id--
          &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.testsite.com%2Fspotify_connect%2F
          &response_type=code
          &scope=user-read-email
```

and get a code in return and I've traced the code towards the curl in Request->send()

the full link is

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?
client_id=--client--&
code=--returned_code--
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.testsite.com%2Fspotify_connect%2F
&client_secret=--secret--
```

I get this in return:

```
 {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}
```

I've tried sending the authorization in the header as well. Same result

```
Authorization: Basic base64_encode(--clientid--:--clientsecret--);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using the

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials
```

is working like a charm, but using the code I get in return does not work.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: ___grant_type parameter is missing___ Whats confusing about that

Comment: Because it's added in the link: grant_type=authorization_code just like the api says.

Comment: I found that if I edit the code to not use **http_build_query($parameters);**

to convert array of parameters into the url-string, but pass the strings directly to the url it works. So how is **http_build_query** destroying the **grant_type= authorization_code**?